# Custom Module Configuration not working

Tags: 8, configuration

I have the following file.

> modules/custom/test_module/config/install/test_module.settings.yml

```
test_module.settings:
    message: 'Hello'
    langcode: 'en'
```

But I am not able to get the following value.

```
$config = \Drupal::config('test_module.settings');
print $config->get('message');
```

I have referred [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8) link.

**UPDATE:**

Removing `test_module.settings:` line solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_module.settings:
    message: 'Hello'
    langcode: 'en'
```

Is that really content of your file? It should only contain:

```
message: 'Hello'
langcode: 'en'
```

Also, Configuration on config/install is only imported when a module is *installed*. If it is an existing module, you need to re-install it or write an update function to initialize the configuration.

You can always use something like print_r($config->get()) to see everything in your config file.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to use these configuration? Means other than `config/install` so that there is no necessary to re-install the module.

Comment: You can import the configuration manually using the single config import UI or a configuration sync but no, there is no process to do anything like that automatically.